# Configure up-arrow to browse through commands starting with already typed characters

Tags: octave, readline

*This is a self-answered post.*

On octave-3.8.2 command line, the up-arrow recalled only commands starting with characters already typed on the current line.

This behaviour has been lost in recent octave (4.2.0) for instance.

How to bring back the previous behaviour ?

Comment: just pointing out I cannot replicate this problem. The default behaviour on my octave installation (4.2.0) is the one you describe for 3.8.2 (i.e. only commands starting with characters already typed are searched)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Your global `~/.inputrc ` probably contains the "history-search-backward" configuration. Mine did not. The point is that in 3.8.2, octave had its own readline configuration.

Comment: my global .inputrc doesn't, but my octave installation provides its own inputrc. You either deleted this file by accident or have an unusual installation / configuration. See my answer below for details of the file that came by default with my installation.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Not at all, please see comment to your answer. Where is your "global .inputrc" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave is now using `~/.inputrc` if present, rather than its default `octave/4.2.0/m/startup/inputrc`.

Another readline configuration can be used at any time [`readline_read_init_file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Customizing-readline.html).

If behaviour is to be shared between all readline programs (`bash` for instance), then just add the following (taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53844/104955), for `bash`) to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
# allow to enter the first characters of a command, 
# and then use the Up and Down keys to move through only those commands 
# in history that begin with that string.
"\e[A": history-search-backward            # arrow up
"\e[B": history-search-forward             # arrow down
```

If this should be done only for octave, one way is to wrap these lines between `$if octave ... $else ... $endif`:

```
$if octave
"\e[A": history-search-backward            # arrow up
"\e[B": history-search-forward             # arrow down
$endif
```

Another way would be to issue a [`readline_read_init_file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Customizing-readline.html)`("~/.octave_inputrc")` in your `~/.octaverc`.

Comment: Ah I see you've edited your answer to include the default octaverc, so I've deleted mine as it's superfluous. You're right, the reason my installation was not affected is because Linux Mint does not have a `.inputrc` file (unless defined explicitly), as it uses a system-wide `/etc/inputrc` by default.

Comment: which, btw, does not contain `history-search-backward`, but it seems octave only checks for a local `.inputrc`, not a system-wide one; if a local one does not exist, the default `inputrc` that comes with octave is used instead.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Exactly. Your answer was an interesting addition, because it mentionned octave's default `inputrc`. Could it be undeleted ? Or would you prefer that we remove all our comments, that might be hard to follow without it ?

Comment: I think your answer is complete as it is at the moment and useful to have on SO. Undeleting mine wouldn't add much at this point, so let's leave it at that :)